# Does System.Data.Sqlite v1.0.81 use SQLlite v3.?

Tags: .net, sqlite, versioning

Where is the table that says what version of Sqlite was compiled into System.Data.Sqlite?

I'm working on a project that references v1.0.81 and I want to know what was fixed since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Sqlite v3.7.12.1.

See the source code here for your distribution:
http://system.data.sqlite.org/downloads/1.0.81.0/sqlite-netFx-source-1.0.81.0.zip

And the version number is in:

```
\SQLite.Interop\src\core\sqlite3.c
```

Answer (score 0):

General information can be found in the [FAQ](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/faq.wiki)

Lots of [download](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) versions, and compilation/release information.

As to a table of versions you'll need to work back from the [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/news.html) version information.

Comment: That version table you linked to is very useful information, but it doesn't list the corresponding System.Data.Sqlite release.